# Сгенерировать верный массив

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(text.textContent.match(/[a-zа-яё0-9]+|\s|[^\w\s]+/gi))
```

```css
  #test, #text {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    max-width: 30%
  }
  p {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div id=text>
Текст

Текст.
Текст Текст.
Текст ТекстТекст Текст.
</div>
```

```
['\n', 'Текст\n', '\n', 'Текст.\n', 'Текст']
```

Работает верно, но в блоке так же присутствуют теги "

"

```js
console.log(text.textContent.match(/[a-zа-яё0-9]+|\s|[^\w\s]+/gi))
```

```css
  #test, #text {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    max-width: 30%
  }
  p {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="text">
<p>Текст</p>
<p>Текст.
Текст Текст.
Текст ТекстТекст Текст.</p>
</div>
```

Тут он не совсем верно работает, в моем случаи выводит

```
['\n', 'Текст\n', 'Текст.\n', 'Текст Текст.\n', 'Текст']
```

Дело тут в теге `<p>`, так как изначально берем текст из блока без html. То пустой строчки он не видит, как мне решить это?

**Как получить в обеих случаях, следующий результат**

```
<style>
 #text {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    max-width: 30%
  }
  p {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
  }
</style>

<div id="text">
<p>Текст</p>
<p>Текст.
Текст Текст.
Текст</p>
</div>
        
<div id="text">
Текст
        
Текст.
Текст Текст.
Текст
</div>
 
Получить в обеих случаях  
['\n', 'Текст\n', '\n', 'Текст.\n', 'Текст']
```

Comment: Напишите ожидаемый результат, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил в конец поста

Comment: А куда `ТекстТекст` делся?

Comment: Это алгоритм ограничил, в последнем примере все верно если с этим текстом `['\n', 'Текст\n', '\n', 'Текст.\n', 'ТекстТекст' , '\n',  'Текст.']`

Answer (score 1):

Вроде просто обычным `split`-ом получилось то что надо:

```js
//Получить в обеих случаях  
//['\n', 'Текст\n', '\n', 'Текст.\n', 'Текст']

const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

texts.forEach(text => {
  const content = text.textContent;
  const parts = content.split('\n');
  
  console.log('Before adding "\\n"', parts); // Впринципе если забить на знак `\n`, то тут уже алгоритм закончен
  
  if (parts[parts.length - 1].trim() === '') parts.pop();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; ++i) {
    parts[i] += '\n';
  }
  
  console.log('After adding "\\n"', parts);
})
```

```css
.text {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  max-width: 30%
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
<p>Текст</p>

<p>Текст.
Текст Текст.
Текст</p>
</div>
        
<div class="text">
Текст

Текст.
Текст Текст.
Текст
</div>
```

Comment: `const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

texts.forEach(text => {
  const content = text.textContent;
  const parts = content.split('\n');
  
  if (parts[parts.length - 1].trim() === '') parts.pop();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; ++i) {
    parts[i] += '\n';
  }
  
  console.log('After adding "\\n"', parts);
})`

Comment: Тоже самое получается `['\n', 'Текст\n', '\n', 'Текст.\n', 'Текст Текст.\n', 'Текст ТекстТекст Текст.']` `['\n', 'Текст\n', 'Текст.\n', 'Текст Текст.\n', 'Текст ТекстТекст Текст.']` Пропадает перенос строки, его нету в том блоке где тег `</p>`

Comment: То есть необходимо добавить перенос строки там где тег `</p>`

Comment: @Лена Пожалуйста прекратите отправлять огромные куски кода в комментариях, это невозможно читать

Comment: @Лена В обоих случаях у меня ответы после `After adding` идентичны друг другу